# Methods to demonstrate time series causality?

Tags: regression, causality

I am working with a team to understand the relationship between two processes that are hypothesized to have a relationship but which occur simultaneously. The hypothesized relationship is that **action A** taken against population P produces **behavior B** in that same population, but I am concerned that **behavior B**, which in many cases occurs without the presence of **action A**, drives some of the observed volume of **action A**.

One proposed approach was to gather observations of **action A** in period $t-1$ and correlate them to the volume of **behavior B** observed in period $t$. I have serious concerns about this approach, as the volume of action A in $t-1$ is more highly correlated with the volume of action A in period $t$ than with behavior B.

I've started by working with correlograms to demonstrate those basic facts but would like to apply a time series approach (perhaps Granger causality testing) to address the issue. Are there other tools or methods available that would address the issue of causality in a time series relationship?